# SqlAlchemy check if a submodel has been modified

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have a Model using the DefaultMeta in SQL Alchemy that has a sub-model:

```
sub_model = relationship(
    'SubModel',
    cascade='delete',
    lazy='select',
    uselist=False,
    backref=backref('my_model', lazy='joined'),
)
```

I understand that I can use `db.session.is_modified(model)` to check if a model has any changes to it, but is there a clean way to check if a sub model has changes?  I'd prefer to not have to specify `db.session.is_modified(model.sub_model)` in my code as I'd prefer  to avoid missing changes to future sub models.